# Structure R Dataframe from Long to Wide

Tags: r

I have a dateframe as such:

```
long <- data.frame(subj = c(1,1,2,2,2), code = c("a", "b", "a", "d", "e"))

   subj code
 1    1    a
 2    1    b
 3    2    a
 4    2    d
 5    2    e
```

I can't seem to structure the data in such a was that `code` repeats 3 times for each `subj` and in each `code.n` is the code in chronological order.

As such:

```
   subj code.1 code.2 code.3
 1    1      a      b   <NA>
 2    2      a      d      e
```

Any and all help appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

We create a sequence column for the grouping column 'subj' and then do `dcast`.  We can use `dcast` from `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(long)`), grouped by 'subj', create the sequence column 'new' and reshape from 'long' to 'wide' with `dcast`.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
setDT(long)[, new:=paste('code', 1:.N, sep='.'), by = subj]
dcast(long, subj~new, value.var='code')
```

---

Or this can be done with `spread` from `tidyr` after creating the sequence column using `dplyr` methods

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
long %>% 
    group_by(subj) %>% 
    mutate(new=paste('code', row_number(), sep='.')) %>% 
    spread(new, code)
```